# Laravel - Carbon ->addmonth() giving random dates?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

We're having problems creating a webhook service for a payment using "Mollie".

Here's the webhook code

```
 public function premiumPaymentCheck(Request $request)
    {
        $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->get(Input::get('id'));
        $metadata = $payment->metadata;
        $user_id = $metadata->user_id;


        if ($payment->isPaid()) {

            $user = User::find($user_id);

            $user->mollie_customerID = $metadata->customerId;
            $user->premium = true;
            $user->premium_type = "premium";
            $user->subscribed = true;
            $user->premium_expire_date = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

            $user->save();
        }
    }
```

Everything works, except for the `premium_expire_date`. From what I understand, it should add 1 month from the payment time *(the time the payment calls the webhook, so Carbon::now())*, but the dates never match.It's always a random date that doesn't really make sense.

Some of the dates are correct, but most of them seem completely of. Any Idea what this might be?

Comment: How far off? Are they consistent (i.e. does running several `Carbon::now()->addMonth()` calls in quick succession give similar or wildly different dates)? What's the column type for the `premium_expire_date` field? What does `Carbon::now()` output for you - is that part accurate?

Comment: No they're all within one month of the desired date, but there really isn't any pattern

Comment: You've only really answered one of my questions. Via the CLI, run `php artisan tinker` and enter `Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth();` Does it give you what you expect?

Comment: if you had problems near the end of the month (e.g. `Carbon::now()` '2016-07-30') beware of month overflow behaviour and `Carbon::addMonthNoOverflow` (see example in [why addMonths() change the day of month?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43068128/264047))

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with carbon. Check your config/app.php file for timezone property.

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

Comment: A timezone issue wouldn't cause the described "random dates".

Answer (score 0):

Timezone is currently:

`'timezone' => 'UTC',`

We are in Belgium/Brussels. So should it be:

`'timezone' => env('Europe/Brussels', 'UTC')`

Alternately it could be:

`'timezone' => 'Europe/Brussels',`

Thanks for the help!